# How to perform an IF statement for duplicate values within the same column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and want to find duplicate values within a column and if found, create a new column add a zero for every duplicate case but leave the original value unchanged.

Original DataFrame:

```
Code1   
1      
2      
3      
4      
5     
1      
2     
1      
1
```

New DataFrame:

```
Code1   Code2
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
1      10
2      20
1      100
1      1000
6      60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount`

```
df.assign(counts = df.groupby("Code1").cumcount(), 
          Code2=lambda x:x["Code1"]*10**(x["counts"])
         ).drop("counts", axis=1)
   Code1  Code2
0      1      1
1      2      2
2      3      3
3      4      4
4      5      5
5      1     10
6      2     20
7      1    100
8      1   1000
```

there might be a solution using transform (but I'm just not having time right now to investigate). However, here it's really explicit about what is happening

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Code1'])

code2 = []

x = {}
for d in data:
    if d not in x:
        x[d] = d
    else:
        x[d] = x[d] * 10

    code2.append(x[d])

df['Code2'] = code2

print(df)
```